# CCS\HTML - Spry menu sub-menu change text on hover

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a spry menu and it has a drop menu I want to have the text change when you hover over the menu button. So what that would look like is when you have the drop down menu open and highlight over one of the menu items the text changes from say `1` to `one`. Is this possible.

My code for the spry menu is as follows:

```
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
 <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#>1-5</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="'>1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

My code for the `css` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css)
and you can see what the menu looks like [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/index.html).

So let me summarize my question. What do I have to do to make my spry menu sub-menu's text change when you highlight over one of the sub-menu items.

I have done some research on this site on this matter with no luck. I have also look at adobe's fourms as well as the documentation on spry menus. As well on Google.

If someone could share some insight on this question would be great.

**Update**

I found an article about changing the text with jQuery and `mouseover` but that would be a pain to type for everything there are 23 different sub menus or is that the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the rollover text in some sort of attribute in the HTML.  This is a very good practice anyways:

```
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li>
    <a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#" title="one-five">1-5</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="" title="one">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="" title="two">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="" title="three">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="" title="four">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="" title="five">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then a small bit of jQuery:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#MenuBar1').on('mouseover', 'a', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr('data-default-text', $this.text()).text( $this.attr('title') );
  }).on('mouseout', 'a', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.text( $this.attr('data-default-text') );
  });
});
</script>
```

Adding a fiddle to show that it is working with the above code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/p6Zwa/

Comment: its not changing the text.

Comment: am i calling the jquery wrong `<script type="text/javascript">code here</script>`

Comment: make sure you are using jQuery and are waiting until the DOM is loaded.  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The "Document Object Model" is considered "loaded" or "ready" once all the HTML has been loaded and parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="submenu">
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="one" default-text="1">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="two" default-text="2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="three" default-text="3">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="four" default-text="4">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-lightbox="five" default-text="5">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can try with Jquery :

first include jquery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

you need more test or store the initial value and the result value in `attributes` for flexibility

```
$("#submenu a").hover(function(){
  if($(this).html() != $this.attr('data-lightbox'))
     $(this).html($this.attr('data-lightbox'));
  else
    $(this).html($this.attr('default-text'));

});
```

});

Comment: You Like when you highlights the 1 submenu the number text of the link will be one? yes?

Comment: As Ryan Wheale detailed more the solution so you can use jquery I will edit my response

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could use the :after pseudo to accomplish this.

```
#menuBar1 li a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
#menuBar1 li a:after {
    color:white;
    content:'1';
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
#menuBar1 li a:hover:after {
    content:'one';
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96jFZ/

Now this might be easier with JavaScript, because with this method you have to have a class or something for every number, while with JavaScript you can use an array and an if statement to change it.